# Layout buttons so each divides up the space equally

Tags: android, layout, button, sizing

Im using a LinearLayout to put two buttons horizontally side-by-side, but I want to each button to size itself to use 50% of the horizontal space. I thought layout_weight of "1" for each button would do the trick, but maybe my layout_width needs to be changed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `layout_weight` attribute controls how much of the *left over* space each of your buttons is given. If your buttons take up different amounts of space to start with, then each of them will first be given the space they ask for, and *then* any remaining space will be divided up between them, meaning that you won't have an exact 50/50 split.

You can get around this behaviour by first setting `layout_width="0px"` (keeping your `layout_weight`s as they are), and relying on 50% being enough space to display each button.

Comment: only layout_weight  1.0 not worked for me. but when add layout_width="0dp" it worked for me.. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

I would set the `layout_width` of each button to `0px`, then use the `layout_weight=1` trick you mentioned.