# How to split screen into equal pieces

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to use some portion of the bottom side for menus or buttons. Then I would like to divide the remaining part into 4 equal pieces to put 4 equal-sized buttons. 
Top-left button
Top-right button
Bottom-left button
Bottom-right button

Something like this: (I'm not allowed to post images).

I tried 2 relative layouts for bottom and top, then 4 linear layouts for big buttons but failed. There should be an easy way for this without using tons of different layouts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For equal devided you can use weight property in to the LinearLayout.

Please see some example which help you how to use weight property in to your screen layout.
Have you seen this [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285150/layout-buttons-so-each-divides-up-the-space-equally)?

Feel free for comments.

Comment: Yes thank you it worked. I got rid of RelativeLayout and used weight just like you said.