# Android layout - Two views next to each other, equal width, use full screen-width

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-layout-weight

I have a problem with a layout in android. I want that two views should have the equal width, and they should almost use the full width of the screen. Each view should contain a centered label.

It should look like this when it's done:

[image: Example]

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I just have placeholder values for the width right now.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using LinearLayout with orientation="horizontal" and weight=1 for both of your views.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use  android:layout_weight attribute in xml so try below code hope it will resolve your problem :-

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <Button
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
        android:text="Not this time"
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of
>   space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to
>   "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view
>   to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight
>   of each view to "1"

[For more info you need to read Linear layout.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier with `LinearLayout`, set the layout to `match_parent` with `horizontal` orientation.

After that, set `layout_width` to `0px` and `layout_weight=1` in both of your `view`.

See this for good explanation :

[Layout buttons so each divides up the space equally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285150/layout-buttons-so-each-divides-up-the-space-equally)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use layout_weight attribute for this.

```
     <Button
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
        android:text="Not this time"
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>
```